# How to capture bank payment info to store for payment processing using Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). Is there any way to capture bank payment info to store for payment processing? So that a customer doesn't need to enter details on each transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Commerce Card on File](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cardonfile)

> Commerce Card on File provides an API and user interface for storing
> and reusing credit card data on subsequent orders within Drupal
> Commerce. **The module does not retain full card numbers locally but
> instead stores the remote ID of the full card data from the payment
> gateway used to validate and process your credit card transactions.**
> This means card on file data will only be good for a single payment
> gateway; if you change payment gateways or accounts, your stored card
> data may no longer be usable.

#### How this module is PCI compliant

This module is safe as it does not retain the full card number. Only the last 3 numbers and expire date are stored in your DB. So if your DB gets hacked, you'll be fine.

Furthermore, when this module connects your payment processor, it uses a token to represent the persons card. Only you can use that token to deposit funds to your account. So even if somehow they intercept the token value, they can't do anything with it.

source: [David Kitchen](https://youtu.be/eI1N8xbB5ZQ?t=8m52s)

---

You should also get Commerce Dunning to deal with expired card numbers.

#### [Commerce Dunning](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_dunning)

> Dunning management (Delinquent User Notification) is the automated
> process that's kicked off when a charge attempt of a recurring order
> fails. This process involves periodic customer communication and
> payment retries.

[Dunning Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-cS6-pmukQ)

Comment: thanks for quick responce after trying this module will let u knw this module fullfilling my need or not

Comment: We received the following error processing your card. Please enter your information again or try a different card.
    A duplicate transaction has been submitted.

Comment: why these errors are comming on checkout page

Comment: @Vicky8888 try following this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI1N8xbB5ZQ you can skip to 13:03

Comment: These are indeed "the" modules to start from. Add to that the "PCI compliance" stuff and you're in great shape for addressing the challenge in this question ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I added some stuff.

Comment: Interesting "stuff" you added ... And interesting "location" of that Drupal Camp where it is from ...

Answer (score 0):

The modules already suggested in the prior answer are indeed the modules I'd also recommend.

However, for way more details (background info) about **capturing** and **storing** these sensitive data, I suggest you also checkout (= listen or watch) what's mentioned in these links:

- [Commerce Subscriptions](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/110), which provides some insights about best practises for processing credit cards, and some more interesting [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) related modules.

  **Topics included**:

  - What is a subscription?
  - Credit Cards
  - Controlling Access to content / Feature
  - Drupal Commerce Components
- [PCI Compliance](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/036), which provides a ton of details about pitfalls to avoid when processing these kinds of data (also mentioned in the previous link).

  **Topics included**:

  - What is PCI Compliance
  - Who is at risk?
  - Validation Types
  - Payment Methods
  - Best approach for Drupal developers

Comment: Very good podscasts

Comment: Merci (oes: thank you) for confirming so ... I agree! And not just these 2 ones ... ALL of them ... And "*my profile picture*" also loves **listening** to them during our daily walks in the woods (where we don't need headsets ...).